# How can I get TextField from inner stage in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have written a controller for two windows /stages. 
The first window is opened in the MainClass. The second in the Controller, if the user clicks onto a button.
How can I get the TextFields from second.fxml in the applyFor()-method?

Thanks.

```
@FXML
    protected void requestNewAccount(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("second.fxml")); // TextFields in there
            Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setTitle("Second Window");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            String css = MainOnlineCustomer.class.getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm();
            scene.getStylesheets().clear();
            scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * closes the "second"-Window
     * @param event
     */
    @FXML
    protected void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
        final Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
        final Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void applyFor(ActionEvent event) {
        // get values from TextField in second.fxml here!!!
    }
```

Comment: Bind the action button to the applyFor method and set an Id for the TextField from second.fxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to share controllers between fxmls unless they serve the same purpose. Here both fxml seem to serve a different purpose (account management, login or something similar for one of them and creating a new account for the other). What is even worse is that those classes do not share the same controller instance, which means the small (and probably only) benefit you could get from using the same controller, is not used here. You should better use different controllers.

Since you use `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL` as modality, I'd recommend using [`showAndWait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) instead of `show` to open the new stage. This will enter a nested event loop, which allows the UI to remain responsive and continues after the invocation of `showAndWait` once the stage is closed.

Furthermore add a method to the controller of `second.fxml` that allows you to retrieve the result.

### Example

This creates a `Person` object with given name and family name.

#### "primary window (opening the "inner" stage)

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("second.fxml"));
Stage subStage = new Stage();
subStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
subStage.setTitle("Second Window");
Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
subStage.setScene(scene);
subStage.showAndWait();

Optional<Person> result = loader.<Supplier<Optional<Person>>>getController().get();

if (result.isPresent()) {
    // do something with the result
}
```

#### controller for "inner" content

```
public class SecondController implements Supplier<Optional<Person>> {
    @FXML
    private TextField givenName;
    @FXML
    private TextField familyName;

    private boolean submitted = false;

    // handler for submit action
    @FXML
    private void submit() {
        submitted = true;
        givenName.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

    // handler for cancel action
    @FXML
    private void cancel() {
        givenName.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Person> get() {
        return submitted ? Optional.of(new Person(givenName.getText(), familyName.getText())) : Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

Note that you can gain access to any data available to the controller this way. I wouldn't recommend accessing any nodes (like `TextField`s) directly though, since this makes changing the UI harder.

Using the `Supplier` interface here is not necessary, but I chose to do this to achieve a loose coupling between `SecondController` and the main window.